# spring boot application can't find server by url

Tags: spring-boot, http-status-code-404

my spring boot can't find the server by URL. after getting the request, it returns a 404 HTTP status code.

I checked the URL and it's correct.

Comment: Add some code .

Comment: add your controller code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check which port your api is running in the log or look at `application.properties` or `application.yml` which port is configured, if its not specified there it would be using the default port.
2. Run [netstat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/netstat) and verify whether the service is running.
3. Look at the controller and cross-check the url you are invoking and HTTP method.